# Changing Header Theme in jquery mobile Page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I Need To Change the `Default(theme a)` Theme of the jquery mobile page header `to (theme c)`

Comment: do read documentation, its pretty good and clear and has a lot of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in their documentation http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-themes.html, you have to specify your theme with `data-theme` attribute.
Ex:

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b"> 
    <h1>Page Title</h1> 
</div>
```